# Testing Unstable_cache from Next not doing what I think it should

Tags: next.js, caching

I can not create the unstable_cache tag..

Looking to store some prisma queries that change very little but are called a lot, in my testing though I am seeing a cached looking response, but appears its running the function call still though.  here is my test code.  I am unaware if this works running local so I added client reports for a miss to client.

here is my test code, pick a number between 0-2, await a random number 0-510 in a function with 4 second delay.  Cache results of the await function via tag key in unstable cache.  When I see the same 0-2 number re-appear its the "same" as previous but appears its still awaiting the function return when I am assuming it should not.

sandbox link https://codesandbox.io/p/devbox/clever-mayer-nczc3p?file=%2Fpackage.json%3A16%2C31

```
import { unstable_cache } from "next/cache";
export const dynamic = "force-dynamic";
import { Suspense } from "react";

export default async function Out() {
  return (
    <div>
      <h2>Test Unstable Cache</h2>
      <Suspense fallback="Grabbing random number">
        <Test />
      </Suspense>
    </div>
  );
}
async function Test() {
  const numberUsed = await getRandomInt(2);
  const cacheValue = `numberUsed_${numberUsed}`;

  console.log(cacheValue);
  // Use async/await to fetch and cache data
  const cacheResponse = await unstable_cache(
    async () => getRandomInt(510), 
    [cacheValue],
    { revalidate: 90000 },
  )();

  console.log(numberUsed + " returns " + cacheResponse);
  let text = numberUsed + " returns " + cacheResponse;

  return text;
}

async function getRandomInt(max) {
  console.log("miss");
  const delay = (ms) => new Promise((res) => setTimeout(res, ms));

  await delay(4000);
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * max);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

unstable_cache is actually working, using the same function to generate the random key for the tag was showing miss,  My mistake here